# Distribute buttons evenly

Tags: html, css

This maybe a fairly easy one, but I'm sucked. How can I evenly distribute horizontally  the 3 image buttons?

```
<div id="mainwrapper">
        <div id="box-1" class="box">
            <img id="image-1" src="images/1.jpg"/>
                <span class="caption simple-caption">
                <div class="minibuttonR"><a href="index.html" onClick=""></a></div>
                <div class="minibuttonC"><a href="index.html" onClick=""></a></div>
                <div class="minibuttonL"><a href="index.html" onClick=""></a></div>
                </span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#mainwrapper .minibuttonL {
    background-image: url(images/bu_spec.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding: 40px;
}
#mainwrapper .minibuttonC {
    background-image: url(images/bu_zoom.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding: 40px;
}
#mainwrapper .minibuttonR {
    background-image: url(images/bu_ok.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

Comment: in ur css add Padding-right:"some number"  (for right) padding-left:"some number" (for left) and position:center (for center)

Comment: Thanks for the response... but did not work?
I replaced padding 40px; to what you had suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (add the CSS `float:left; margin-right:10px;` to the button elements.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mfd4r/3/)

**CSS**

```
#mainwrapper .minibuttonL, #mainwrapper .minibuttonC, #mainwrapper .minibuttonR {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding: 40px; float:left; margin-right:10px;
}

#mainwrapper .minibuttonL {
    background-image: url(images/bu_spec.jpg);
}

#mainwrapper .minibuttonC {
    background-image: url(images/bu_zoom.jpg);

}

#mainwrapper .minibuttonR {
    background-image: url(images/bu_ok.jpg);
}
```

And after the buttons add this small div to clear the floats of the above buttons:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks danni.  'bu_zoom.jpg' seems to be correctly positioned but 'bu_ok.jpg' appears in the left corner (should actually be on the right) and 'bu_spec.jpg' is not visible?

Comment: @user3098940 See my updated answer. That problem should be solved.

Comment: 'bu_ok.jpg' is still in the wrong position. It appears that 'bu_spec.jpg' and 'bu_ok.jpg' are overlapping?  I switched <div class="minibuttonR"> and <div class="minibuttonL"> - that's how I noticed that the buttons are overlapping.

Comment: @user3098940 Hmm.. Strange. I have tested with several different images and they are not overlapping each other. But what you are saying is that the image 'bu_ok.jpg' is stretching across 'bu_zoom.jpg' to 'bu_spec.jpg'?

Comment: It's not visible at all. Whatever is the last <DIV> (html)- it's not showing. example: if <div class="minibuttonR"> is the last one <div class="minibuttonL"> doesnot show. If <div class="minibuttonL"> is the last one <div class="minibuttonR"> does not show.

Comment: @user3098940 Here is an update with images: http://jsfiddle.net/Mfd4r/5/ I see nothing wrong. All buttons are visible.

Comment: <img id="image-1" src="images/1.jpg"/> is missing from your sample (3rd line). Is that causing the issue?    Out of the 3 buttons whatever is the last <DIV> (html)- it's not showing. example: if <div class="minibuttonR"> is the first one <div class="minibuttonL"> doesnot show. If <div class="minibuttonL"> is the first one <div class="minibuttonR"> does not show.

Comment: @user3098940 Can you please link a fiddle with how you modified my code? I think the problem can be solved much quicker that way.

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/8Hhh9/   The last button is not inline.

Comment: @user3098940 The last button is not inline for two reasons: **1)** Add CSS to `<img id="image-1" src="images/1.jpg"/>` so that it also floats (for example just add `float:left` (I assume you want the image to be in line with the 3 buttons). **2)** Change the CSS code: `width: 235px;` for `#mainwrapper .box` to make sure all buttons can fit in one 'line'.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to correct problem 1 is to change `#mainwrapper .minibuttonL, #mainwrapper .minibuttonC, #mainwrapper .minibuttonR` to `#mainwrapper .minibuttonL, #mainwrapper .minibuttonC, #mainwrapper .minibuttonR, #image-1` to make the image float with the buttons on one line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distribute them equally and center them, you should give the parent element a `text-align: center` and the children (the buttons), a `display: inline-block` attribute.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Mfd4r/2/

This will help: http://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/